# Open App Store and iTunes on iOS and go to default page, not a specific app or item

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, itunes

I'm attempting to open iTunes and the App Store on iOS but instead of the typical desire to go to a specific application I'd like to go to the section that allows you to redeem a code.

To start with I'd like to be able to just open the applications without directing them to a specific item in either of the stores, i.e. to the featured page, top 25, whatever.

The closest I've gotten is using itms: or itms-apps: without any additional information.  This prompts the user with an error saying that the store is unreachable and leaves them at a blank page in the application.  This isn't really the error as they can click on any button in the app and it will load just fin.

Bonus points for a link that lets them enter the redemption code directly from where the link takes them.

EDIT: Clarification, I'm not having them enter a promo code, the user would be entering what amounts to an iTunes giftcard code that they have been provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to link to the appstore and to special apps and developers, but I can't find any solution for you. The link to a specific promocode might help you. Anyways, take a look:
http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks

If you have questions write a comment below.

Comment: I'm aware of the ability to link to specific apps or accounts that will show the listing of their apps.  What additional information can you provide around the "specific promocode" solution?

Comment: for specific promocodes I didnt found a solution, but for the top 25 I have a link, this might help you, but I think it first opens safari and then it opens the store. here try this and put it in the Ibaction, whatever. http://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/paid-apps/

Comment: I also found a funny and helpful tool at the web: http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

Comment: well I tried to find anything but I'm sorry, theres no solution for you.